# ActiveRecord query to get x results and y results

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model, `Suggestion`, that has a few attributes, including `moderated: boolean` and `created_at: datetime`. I am trying to run a query where I get *both* the `Suggestions` that are moderated **and** the `Suggestions` that have *not* been moderated but were created over 4 days ago.

I know there is a much simpler query I can run, but couldn't figure it out so just put this together. I realize this solution is wrong and not adhering to KISS, which I try to do.

```
all_suggestions       = Suggestion.all

moderated_suggestions = all_suggestions.where(moderated: true)
older_suggestions     = all_suggestions.where('created_at < ?', 4.days.ago)
```

Then I'm converting to arrays and concatenating the two arrays, which then I sort. Like this:

```
concatenated_arrays = moderated_suggestions.to_a.concat older_suggestions.to_a
concatenated_arrays.sort! { |t1, t2| t2.created_at <=> t1.created_at }
```

This seems like way too much for a simple query. How can I simplify this query and get the same results??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't this what you want? All moderated and all non moderated but more than 4 days old

```
Suggestion.where("moderated = ? or (created_at < ? and moderated = ?)", true, 4.days.ago, false).order("created_at")
```